# Rails - Hiding option for Activities

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ruby-on-rails

So I would like to implement a hiding option for my app where the user can click on the hide icon and it would hide the respective activity from the home view. The plan is to implement that and then another button that "unhides" the activities once clicked. I have already set up the boolean value, named "hidden" for the table already but I am having trouble getting the Javascript working as I would like to.

Here is the code for the home.html.erb view for activity:

```
<!--home.html.erb-->

<!--<h1>Time Tracker</h1>
<li><%= link_to 'Login', login_new_path %></li> -->

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <!-- The above 3 meta tags *must* come first in the head; any other head content must come *after* these tags -->
  <title>Bootstrap 101 Template</title>
  <link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='../stylesheets/bootstrap.min.css'/>
  <script src='../javascripts/bootstrap.min.js'></script>
  <!-- Bootstrap -->
  <!--<link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"> -->

  <!-- HTML5 shim and Respond.js for IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
  <!-- WARNING: Respond.js doesn't work if you view the page via file:// -->
  <!--[if lt IE 9]>
  <![endif]-->
</head>
<body>
<!--
<style>
.navbar {
  background-color:#2F4F4F
}
</style>
-->
<nav class="navbar navbar-default">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" aria-expanded="false">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">TimeTracker</a>
    </div>

    <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li class="active"><a href="#">Activities<span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a></li>
      </ul>
      </li>
      </ul>
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li><a href="#">Signed in as Admin</a></li>
        <li class="dropdown">
          <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Settings <span class="caret"></span></a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a href="#">Profile</a></li>
            <!--
            <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
            -->
            <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
            <li><a href="#">Account Settings</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
  </div><!-- /.container-fluid -->
</nav>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.0.3/css/font-awesome.min.css">

<span>Change This</span>
<div id="activity_container">
  <input type="text" class="rename"/> <!--***NEW to edit -->
  <input type="button" value="rename"/> <!--***NEW to edit -->
  <ul class="list-group-sortable" id="Activities" >
    <h1 align = "center">Activities</h1>
    <% @activities.each do |activity| %>
        <li class="list-group-item" id="item" style="list-style: none;">
          <input type="text" class="edit" /> <!-- New 3/28 -->
          <input type="button" value="rename" class="showButton"/> <!--***NEW to edit -->
          <%= activity.a_name %>
          <%= link_to activity, method: :delete, data: { confirm: "Are you sure?" } do %>
              <i class="fa fa-trash-o" aria-hidden="true" title="Delete"></i>
          <% end %>
          <i onclick="editClick()" class="fa fa-pencil fa-fw" aria-hidden="true" title="Edit" id="editActivity"></i>
          <button id="hideActivity" style="border:none; padding:0">
            <i class="fa fa-eye" aria-hidden="true" title="Hide" id="item"></i>
          </button>
        </li>
    <% end %>
  </ul>
</div>

<ul class="pager">

  <li class="previous"><a href="#"><span aria-hidden="true">&larr;</span>Previous </a></li>
  <li class="next"><a href="#"> Next<span aria-hidden="true">&rarr;</span></a></li>
</ul>

<!-- *****************NEW*********************** -->
<%= form_for @activity do |a| %>
    <%= a.text_field :a_name, id: 'a_name_field', placeholder: 'Activity Name'%>
    <%= a.submit 'Create', id: 'submitButton', class: 'btn btn-primary'%>
<% end %>


<!-- ***************************************** -->

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#unfilled").click(function(){
            if($("#unfilled").attr("src") == "<%=asset_path('unfilledbubble.png')%>"){
                $("#unfilled").attr("src", "<%=asset_path('filledbubble.png')%>");
            }else{
                $("#unfilled").attr("src", "<%=asset_path('unfilledbubble.png')%>");
            }
        });
    });
</script>
<!-- jQuery (necessary for Bootstrap's JavaScript plugins) -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Include all compiled plugins (below), or include individual files as needed -->
<script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script> <!-- NEW 3/23 -->
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-sortable/0.9.13/jquery-sortable-min.js"></script>

<script src="jquery.sortable.js"></script>
<script>
    function myFunction() {
        var x = document.getElementById("mySelect");
        x.remove(x.selectedIndex);
    }
    $( function() {
        $('#Activities').sortable({
            containment: '#activity_container',
            cursorAt: {left:event.offsetX, top:event.offsetY}, //to keep item near cursor NOT WORKING
            update: function (event, ui) { //to save order NOT WORKING
                var data = $(this).sortable('serialize');
                // POST to server using $.post or $.ajax
                $.ajax({
                    data: data,
                    type: 'POST',
                    url: 'localhost:3000/activities'
                });
            }
        });
        $('#Activities').disableSelection();
    });

    var chosenValue;
    var chosenIndex;
    var newValue;

    //New 3/29 hide activity
    var index;
    //    $( 'li' ).click(function() {
    //
    //        index = $('li').index(this);
    //        $('li').eq(index).hide();
    //        $('span').text("That was li index #" + index);
    //    });
    $('#hideActivity').click(function() {
        index = $('li').index(this);
        $('li').eq(index).hide("slow"); //deletes everything //$(this).hide('li') deletes logo //$(this).closest('li').hide() only deletes first one
//
        $('span').text("That was div index #" + index);
    });
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Near the bottom, is commented out Javascript code:

```
//    $( 'li' ).click(function() {
//
//        index = $('li').index(this);
//        $('li').eq(index).hide();
//        $('span').text("That was li index #" + index);
//    });
```

When the above code is uncommented and the proceeding Javascript code for the "hideActivity" is commented out, the hiding works but it does so when the user simply clicks on the list item with the activity name instead of just the hide icon. I want to allow the user to sort their activities in whichever order they wish so that is why this code is not exactly what I want.

With that code commented out, the "hideActivity" function is what I tried to use for the icon but when I go to the page and click on the hide icon, the resulting text in the span tag states that the index is -1, which means that it could not find an index.

I suspect that the "index = $('li').index(this);", particularly the keyword "this", is the main problem but I do not know why it works for the commented code but not this one.

Any help or advice would be appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple of issues:

- You shouldn't use an id value more than once on a page so you want to change

  ```
  <button id="hideActivity"
  ```

  to

  ```
  <button class="hideActivity"
  ```
- You set your handler as:

  ```
  $( 'li' ).click(
  ```

This will handle a click anywhere inside any `li` element on your page, not necessarily inside the hide button. Some `li` elements aren't even part of your list. You should scope it more narrowly as

```
    $('#Activities li .hideActivity').click( ....
```

So your code should probably look something like:

```
$( '#Activities li .hideActivity' ).click(function() {
    var index = $('#Activities li .hideActivity').index(this);
    $(this).closest('li').hide();
    $('span').text("That was .hideActivity index #" + index);
});
```

Note the `var` keyword before the index. You don't want to give the variable global scope.